# Close as Duplicate always lists same (unrelated) questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

For at least the past week or so, every time that I go to close a question in the iOS/iphone/related tags, it ALWAYS includes this question as the top candidate for closing:  [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1083701/937822).

For instance, I voted to close this question: [How to parse the string "2013-06-13T05:47:03.737Z" to NSDate object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17617656/937822) as a duplicate (which has absolutely nothing to do with the referenced question) and it showed up again, right at the top.

I'm guessing that it is picking it up just from the tags (the question that it is returning is one of the most highly upvoted questions in the tag), but there should be at least some matching content in the title or question itself before it suggests another question as a duplicate.

Comment: Note the tags are very general in the question. These are very influenetal in the heuristics for related questions. If someone tags it crappy, it gets crappy related and dup suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate it today. It must have been a passing glitch or something that has been fixed.

Comment: Try looking at any question with the iphone tag (that doesn't already have a vote to close as duplicate).  It includes [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk) as a possible duplicate (even when it clearly isn't).

Comment: @lnafziger: [I can totally reproduce this.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qq1Um.png) +1 to your report.

Comment: That is probably because that question has [118 duplicates or linked questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1083701?lq=1). I am not quite sure this is not the expected behavior

Comment: Well, it should be a **related** question though, right??  Just because it is highly upvoted in the same tag doesn't automatically mean that it is related....